# Downloading a PWA to a users home screen?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile

When 'the box' appears allowing a mobile user to download a progressive web app (PWA) to their home screen, can 'the box' be customized?

Many users see the box and immediately hit the X. We would like to add our own messaging and try to generate additional participation by helping the user understand the purpose of 'the box' by customizing it.

I would appreciate any feedback on if there is I a way to customize the box so the user better understands its purpose.

Comment: what is "the box"?

Comment: Fabio - When a user views a pwa on their mobile device, 'a box' appears that allows the user to click download to their homescreen. It can be considered a popup or spamish and the user often clicks X to close.    Does that make sense?      We would like to customize it but so far can't.

Comment: I have never seen this on my devices, and I am writing PWA's. To download to the homescreen I have a menu item in the browser menu ("Add to Home Screen") in Android and in iOS

Comment: Fabio - To be more specific, it is the download banner on an Android device that allows a user to add to their home screen. Can the banner be customized?    Have you created a different process for a user to download the pwa? Can you share an example please?

Comment: Are you meaning the banner which opens after the user selects "Add to homescreen"? That banner simply contains your PWA's icon and the app name (both of these informations are in the manifest). What do you need to customize?